# Insert column depending on dbms

Tags: liquibase

I am working with liquibase and I need to support MSSQL and Oracle, but on MSSQL there are no sequences and the column must be an auto-increment, for Oracle I need to have a sequence.

How would I do the inserts without having 2 of them, one because Oracle will use the sequence and another for MSSQL where I would omit the id column. Sadly the column definitions for liquibase do not support the dbms parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have a similar setup, supporting DB2 (2 flavours), Oracle, and MS SQL Server. For the first three we use sequences, but for SQL Server we use identity columns.

I'm in the process of moving us to Liquibase just now (from the horror of maintaining four sets of SQL scripts), and for this situation I'm using the `modifySql` tag. So within each changeset that has a `createTable`, we follow it with something like this:

```xml
<modifySql dbms="mssql">
    <replace replace="[ID] INT" with="[ID] INT IDENTITY"/>
</modifySql>
```

That changes the generated SQL, replacing the `[ID] INT` clause with `[ID] INT IDENTITY`, which turns it into an autoincrementing column.

Along with that we have appropriate `dbms` entries in the `createSequence` changesets:

```xml
<changeSet dbms="oracle,db2,db2i" author="mccallim (generated)" id="1419011907193-1">
    <createSequence schemaName="${main.schema}" cacheSize="100" cycle="false" incrementBy="1" minValue="1" sequenceName="SEQ_ALLOWEDCURRENCIES" startValue="1"/>
</changeSet>
```

**Updated to add data insertion**

Here's how we add data to a table with a column like the above. Here the column `HOSTGROUPID` is autoincrementing on MS SQL. The trick is to to set a special condition that allows you to insert values from your script. I'm assuming that's what you'd want.

```xml
<changeSet author="mccallim (generated)" id="1419001537990-22">
    <sql dbms="mssql">
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT HOSTGROUP ON;
    </sql>
    <insert tableName="HOSTGROUP">
        <column name="HOSTGROUPID" valueNumeric="1"/>
        <column name="GROUPDESCRIPTION" value="SYSTEM"/>
        <column name="CENTREID" valueNumeric="1"/>
        <column name="ARCHIVECONTROL" valueNumeric="2"/>
        <column name="ARCHIVETIME"/>
        <column name="ARCHIVEOFFSET" valueNumeric="10"/>
        <column name="ARCHIVE" valueNumeric="1"/>
        <column name="PRINTEODREPORTS" valueNumeric="0"/>
        <column name="EODREPORTTYPE"/>
        <column name="CONTROLLINGHOSTID"/>
    </insert>
    <sql dbms="mssql">
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT HOSTGROUP OFF;
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: That will work for the schema, but my main question is about the <insert> statements we need for some base data that the system needs, is there any easy way to make a single file for the multiple DBMS? specially the MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

The way we do this is to have two different changesets. One for oracle and one for all other dbms types (in our case it's only mySQL):

```xml
<changeSet author="john" id="common-1_0-1a" dbms="oracle">
    <createSequence sequenceName="hibernate_sequence"
        startValue="1" incrementBy="1" />
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="bob" id="common-1_0-1b">
    <preConditions>
        <not><dbms type="oracle"/></not>
    </preConditions>
    <createTable tableName="hibernate_sequence">
        <column name="next_val" type="BIGINT" />
    </createTable>
    <insert tableName="hibernate_sequence">
        <column name="next_val" valueNumeric="1" />
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```